# Formatting when doing a Cut and Paste from C# to XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, textbox, copy-paste

I am creating a xsd Schema using Visual Studio and have a Ton of Xml files that have information in them that I need to add to the schema, I finally decided it was just taking too long doing it all manually, so I decided to write a small parser. The C# App works fine, It parses through the xml file and Displays the completed lines in a Textbox.  Using the Cut feature of the Textbox, I paste the code into my xsd file, and this is where the problem comes in.

Here is the line causing the problem.

```
textBox1.Text += string.Format("<xs:element minOccurs\"0\" name=\"{0}\">{1}", reader.Value, Environment.NewLine);
```

In my App's C# Textbox this line displays just fine, it shows up like so:

```
<xs:element minOccurs"0" name="GreatWorkSlots">
```

It also shows up fine on NotePad++ in a xml file.

However when it actually gets pasted into a xml or xsd file in visual studio it adds a few extra quotes " and looks like this:

```
<xs:element minOccurs"""0" name="GreatWorkSlots">
```

Can anyone tell me what may be causing this issue?

*Edit* if I create a Text File using Visual Studio and paste the line into that text file it shows up fine, it only seems to be an issue with pasteing into a VS xml or xsd file.

roadmaster

Comment: I cannot reproduce your copy/paste complaint. There is obviously some important context missing from your question. But in the meantime, I will suggest that you probably intended your format to read `minOccurs=\"0\"` instead of `minOccurs\"0\"`. And who knows? Maybe there's something about the context in which you're pasting that causes that typo to result in the extra double quotation marks.

Comment: Yes I just realized that the = was not in there and after adding it into the problem line its now working, I have no clue why it was putting the triple quotes in there. but its working now. thanks.

Comment: Great...glad to hear you got it working. I have voted to close as off-topic, with the reason _"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."_. In other words, while I'm happy there was a solution, this question doesn't seem like it would be helpful to preserve as part of the Stack Overflow corpus.